# consistent spacing using tabular/ minipage/ parbox

Tags: tables, spacing, minipage

Even though I've read numerous threads on how to achieve consistent spacing, I still cannot figure out, why it doesn't work when using any of the macros \testD to \testG in the following example.

(The text looks perfectly fine when using macros \testA (as it is done in the example) to \testC.)

Any help on how to fix macros \testD to \testG would be highly appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{paralist}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\newcommand{\text}{%
    Hello abc abc  abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc gabc 
}

% \testA -> \testC working nicely (consistent spacing)
%
\newcommand\testA{%
    \text\\
    \text

    \text
}
\newcommand\testB{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
        \text\\
        \text\\
        \text
    \end{tabular}
}
\newcommand\testC{%
    \begin{compactitem}
        \item \text
        \item \text
    \end{compactitem}

    \text
}

% \testD-\testG: space between 2nd and 3rd paragraph...
%
\newcommand\testD{% ...TOO SMALL
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
        \text\\
        \text
    \end{tabular}

    \text
}
\newcommand\testE{% ...TOO LARGE
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
        \text\\
        \text
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
        \text
    \end{tabular}
}
\newcommand\testF{% ...TOO SMALL
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \text\\
        \text\strut
    \end{minipage}

    \text
}
\newcommand\testG{% ...TOO SMALL
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
        \text\\
        \text\strut
    }

    \text
}

\begin{document}

    \testA

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

tex tries to keep rows `\baselineskip` apart but if the depth of one row plus the height of the next is already close to or more than `\baselinekip` it gives up on that and instead just inserts a fixed `\lineskip` glue. a minipage or tabular with `[t`] has everything but the height of the top row in the depth so the following box is just separated by `\lineskip` glue.

using `[b]` on the first table and where needed `[t]` on the top solves that issue.

%

```
\newcommand\testD{% ...TOO SMALL
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
        \text\\
        \text
    \end{tabular}

    \text
}
\newcommand\testE{% ...TOO LARGE
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
        \text\\
        \text
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
        \text
    \end{tabular}
}
```

but if you have more than two items and want to control the spacing between all of them it is harder as using `[b]` on the first tabular makes it easy to control the space below but not the space above.

Classically the easiest way if yoou do need to stack multiple such items (if your tables just have normal text) is to arrange that there is a `\strut` in (at least) the first and last line of each box, and use `\lineskip=0pt` so you get no extra space added, and the spacing is not affected by the presence of descenders in the text as a \strut is deeper than all standard letters.